# Visual for masses on a string using ivisual

Tags: python, numpy, vpython

Hi I am trying to create a visual for a physics problem using [ivisual](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/IVisual). The best visual I could find to describe the problem is below:

[image: http://users.wfu.edu/choss/images/phy113/fig1.12.png]

The problem I am having is I found an example in a text book of the same problem. The textbook visualizes the answers using visual module, however from the research I have been doing I believe that the visual module is now called ivisual. I can get the answer numerically when I hash out the function call and any other code that uses the ivisual module. In my specific example the masses are 10 and 20 and the length of each rope segment is 3, 4, and 4, and the distance between a and a is 8. I tried fixing the visual code, but I cannot get it work, it is probably something stupid.

My code is below with the error I am currently getting:

```
from ivisual import *
from numpy.linalg import solve
import numpy as np
import math as m

scene = display(x=0,y=0,width=500,height=500,
                title='String and masses configuration')
tempe = curve(x=range(0,500),color=color.black)

n = 9
eps = 1*10**(-6)
deriv = np.zeros( (n, n), float)
f = np.zeros( (n), float)
x = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1., 1., 1.])

def plotconfig():
    for obj in scene.objects:
        obj.visible=0           # to erase the previous configuration
    L1 = 3.0
    L2 = 4.0
    L3 = 4.0
    xa = L1*x[3]                # L1*cos(th1)
    ya = L1*x[0]                # L1 sin(th1)
    xb = xa+L2*x[4]             # L1*cos(th1)+L2*cos(th2)
    yb = ya+L2*x[1]             # L1*sin(th1)+L2*sen(th2)
    xc = xb+L3*x[5]             # L1*cos(th1)+L2*cos(th2)+L3*cos(th3)
    yc = yb-L3*x[2]             # L1*sin(th1)+L2*sen(th2)-L3*sin(th3)
    mx = 100.0                  # for linear coordinate transformation
    bx = -500.0                 # from 0=< x =<10
    my = -100.0                 # to    -500 =<x_window=>500
    by = 400.0                  # same transformation for y
    xap = mx*xa+bx              # to keep aspect ratio
    yap = my*ya+by
    ball1 = sphere(pos=(xap,yap), color=color.cyan,radius=15) 
    xbp = mx*xb+bx
    ybp = my*yb+by
    ball2 = sphere(pos=(xbp,ybp), color=color.cyan,radius=25) 
    xcp = mx*xc+bx
    ycp = my*yc+by
    x0 = mx*0+bx
    y0 = my*0+by
    line1 = curve(pos=[(x0,y0),(xap,yap)], color=color.yellow,radius=4)
    line2 = curve(pos=[(xap,yap),(xbp,ybp)], color=color.yellow,radius=4)
    line3 = curve(pos=[(xbp,ybp),(xcp,ycp)], color=color.yellow,radius=4)
    topline = curve(pos=[(x0,y0),(xcp,ycp)], color=color.red,radius=4)

def F(x, f):                    # Define F function
    f[0] = 3*x[3]  +  4*x[4]  +  4*x[5]  -  8.0
    f[1] = 3*x[0]  +  4*x[1]  -  4*x[2]
    f[2] = x[6]*x[0]  -  x[7]*x[1]  -  10.0
    f[3] = x[6]*x[3]  -  x[7]*x[4]
    f[4] = x[7]*x[1]  +  x[8]*x[2]  -  20.0
    f[5] = x[7]*x[4]  -  x[8]*x[5]
    f[6] = pow(x[0], 2)  +  pow(x[3], 2)  -  1.0
    f[7] = pow(x[1], 2)  +  pow(x[4], 2)  -  1.0
    f[8] = pow(x[2], 2)  +  pow(x[5], 2)  -  1.0

def dFi_dXj(x, deriv, n):       # Define derivative function
    h = 1*10**(-4)                                             
    for j in range(0, n):
         temp = x[j]
         x[j] = x[j] +  h/2.
         F(x, f)                                                 
         for i in range(0, n):  deriv[i, j] = f[i] 
         x[j] = temp

    for j in range(0, n):
         temp = x[j]
         x[j] = x[j] - h/2.
         F(x, f)
         for i in range(0, n): deriv[i, j] = (deriv[i, j] - f[i])/h
         x[j] = temp

for it in range(1, 100):
      rate(1)                   # 1 second between graphs
      F(x, f)                              
      dFi_dXj(x, deriv, n)   
      B = np.array([[-f[0]], [-f[1]], [-f[2]], [-f[3]], [-f[4]], [-f[5]],[-f[6]], [-f[7]], [-f[8]]])      
      sol = solve(deriv, B)
      dx = np.take(sol, (0, ), 1)      # take the first column of matrix sol
      for i in range(0, n):
        x[i]  = x[i]  +  dx[i]
      plotconfig()
      errX = errF = errXi = 0.0

      for i in range(0, n):
        if ( x[i] !=  0.): errXi = abs(dx[i]/x[i])
        else:  errXi = abs(dx[i])
        if ( errXi > errX): errX = errXi                            
        if ( abs(f[i]) > errF ):  errF = abs(f[i])        
        if ( (errX <=  eps) and (errF <=  eps) ): break

print('Number of iterations = ', it)
print('Solution:')
for i in range(0, n):
        print('x[', i, '] =  ', x[i])
```

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-78050c1f23ab> in <module>()
     76       for i in range(0, n):
     77         x[i]  = x[i]  +  dx[i]
---> 78       plotconfig()
     79       errX = errF = errXi = 0.0
     80 

<ipython-input-5-78050c1f23ab> in plotconfig()
     10 
     11 def plotconfig():
---> 12     for obj in scene.objects:
     13         obj.visible=0           # to erase the previous configuration
     14     L1 = 3.0

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

Comment: `ivisual` seems to be more like an add-on or modification to the original `visual`, that still exists at [vpython.org](http://vpython.org).

Comment: On the site vpython.org it says that to make it work in ipython, (which is what I use) I should use the ivisual module, so I'm not sure where the visual module comes in if I'm using ipython.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example : It works like it is, but first install vpython this way

```
pip install vpython (after to upgrade : --upgrade)
pip install ivisual --upgrade
```

If you work system wide

```
sudo -H pip.....
```